# seafile docker - how to persist config/make container disposable

Tags: docker, seafile-server

I'm building a `seafile` docker based on https://github.com/JensErat/docker-seafile and https://github.com/foxel/seafile-docker, but can't figure out exactly where's *all* the configuration seafile uses.

Note I'm going with sqlite installation, not mysql.
There's a `conf` directory in the installation dir, but that alone can't be it.
Data dir can be easily externalised using docker volumes. Same could be done with `conf` dir, but as I said, this alone can't be enough.

So, question is - how to make seafile docker disposable? As in if docker container gets wiped, how to re-set it up so the already existing data and settings could be used?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how I managed not seeing the documentation on the backups: https://manual.seafile.com/maintain/backup_recovery.html

Apparently you need to make backups of the sqlite db files (assuming you're on sqlite3 installation, not mysql) and the whole data dir.

So there's not a really clean way of doing what I'm trying. Guess I'll put the whole seafile installation and data files to a volume that can be used with a dummy docker container. This way the whole setup can be easily backed up as well.